# stackoverflow newest questions ask 1 hours ago for all tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, newest-questions

I just check & feel strange as all of the tags on SO sites having the newest question asked **1 hour ago**. How it can be possible that questions are not being asked in any of the tag since after that ?

[image]

Checkout this tags: [php](/questions/tagged/php)[java](/questions/tagged/java)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[android](/questions/tagged/android)

Has anyone notice that yet ? Is something strange going on ? Or it just be co-incident ?

Comment: Cache, it's always cache.

Comment: [Works on my machine.](http://blog.pravesh.me/files/2012/08/worksonmymachine.jpg)

Comment: @slugster - seems it just gets solved.