# Newest questions not updating for about one hour on Saturday mornings

Tags: support, newest-questions

Before you close this as a duplicate: this is not the same as any of the following:

- [Can't see new questions on SO (tagged questions)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179662/175984)
- [Newest questions not updating [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179667/175984)
- [stackoverflow newest questions ask 1 hours ago for all tags [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179665/175984)

What I see is the behavior described in all the questions above. However, it is not a one-time deal, as described in the first question, because the same thing happens regularly, every Saturday morning around 10 AM. The problem stays for an hour or less, and then it fixes itself automatically.

Is there a setting that I should change on my side (I'm using Google Chrome on OS X), or is there some setting on stackexchange infrastructure side?

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216676/blank-screen-on-se-2-0-sites/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced it is [just you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214004/182513).

I just noticed this issue this morning.  As I am writing this, the newest question on SO that I see is 27 minutes old and the newest question on MSO is 1 hour old.  And I know for a fact that there is a newer question on MSO as I saw it briefly and visited it, but now don't see it in the question feed, but it wasn't deleted as I can still see it in my browser history.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214033/182513 is the MSO question in question.  I actually think it might have impacting multiple users is it took almost 15 minutes for the question to get closed.  Additionally for the 10 minutes that the post was not showing in the newest questions, it only picked up 1 close vote (other than mine) but was finally closed only a couple of minutes after it showed back up.

The issue seems to have corrected itself as the missing question on MSO finally showed up again a minute or 2 ago, which was 10 minutes after it was asked.  Likewise, SO started updating as well.

Seems to have started for me ~10:20am local time which should be about 3:20pm UTC.  I'll have to see if it does it again around the same time next weekend.

Comment: You are right, I saw it this morning again at someone else's place. I tried different browsers and different computers, but the problem remained. Now that you have confirmed the same thing, I am convinced that the problem is on the Stack Exchange's side. Thank you very much!