# Only old questions in the questions tab

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, questions, homepage, questions-page

I noticed that there isn't newest questions in the questions page. But in front page, those new questions are displayed. Image:

[image]

Is this a bug?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest
- https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: It seems to be the issue for multiple sites in the network at the moment. Some glitching going on.

Comment: Yea, i also noticed that frequent tab doesn't show any questions...

Comment: I wonder if this is related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208690/newest-questions-not-updating-for-about-one-hour-on-saturday-mornings).  I've seen this happen before on Saturdays about this time in the past.

Comment: The only way I found this specific question again is in my browser history.  It isn't showing up in the "/questions" nor in the front page of meta at the moment

Comment: This question has nothing to do with your "duplicate" @Martijn

Comment: Please remove the duplicate.

Comment: @aksu the bug described in that question (or specifically the root cause of that big) might be the same, that's why he linked it.